# connected component of subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G= (V,E)$ be a graph and $H$ be a subgraph of $G$. Prove that every connected component of $H$ is a subgraph of some connected component of $G$.

I think I should start by considering the components of $H$. So let $H_1,\cdots, H_a$ be the components of $H$ and $G_1,\cdots, G_c$ be the components of $G$. Each is a connected subgraph of $G$. Let $1\leq i\leq a.$ It suffices to find $j$ so that $H_i$ is a subgraph of $G_j,$ though I'm not quite sure how to show the existence of this.

Comment: What is your definition of connected component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V(H_i)$ be the set of vertices of $H_i$ then $V(H_i) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{c} V(H_i)\cap V(G_j)$. Since $H_i$ is connected at most one the intersection of the union in nonempty. So this shows that for some $j, V(H_i) \subset V(G_j)$. And we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the subgraph relation is transitive. Since $H_i \subseteq H$ and $H \subseteq G$, we have $H_i \subseteq G$. Since $H_i$ is a component of $H$, it is connected. This implies $H_i$ is a connected subgraph of $G$. If $H_i$ is a maximally connected subgraph of $G$, then it is a component of $G$. If not, then it must be a proper subgraph of a component of $G$.